# menu mandando a primeira li para ultima li

Tags: css

tenho um `menu` com `submenu`, e esse `submenu` pega 100% da div `pai` que é `900px`, as `li pai` ficam no centro, eu queria mandar elas para o direita dei um `float: right` na `#wrapper #top .menu ul li` só que ele inverteu as ordens das minhas `li`, o primeiro `link` passou a ser o último, como poderia arrumar isso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.menu ul {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.menu ul li:first-child {
  margin: 0 11px 0 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 39px;
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: .9s;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fc2827;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.menu ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #000;
}

.menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}

.menu ul ul li a {
  text-align: left;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pesquisar</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="sub_menu">pesquisar</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Reportar erro</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gêneros</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="sub_menu">generos</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

reparem que a formatação correspondente as minhas `li` estão com `float: right;`

Comment: Car aestá um pouco confuso para entender o que está acontecendo... Os links parece que estão na ordem certa pelo código que vc postou na pergunta pelo menos... Tb parece que está faltando parte do css na pergunta pois a página não se comporta como vc está descrevendo... Teria como vc editar a pergunta e incluir um print com o problema na tela?

Comment: @hugocsl editei a pergunta, eu dou um `float:right` na `li` e o primeiro link se torna o ultimo assim em diante, entendeu ?

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro, para corrigir isso existem várias opções, a mais simples é retirar o float das LI e colocar um simples `text-align:right ` na UL, na minha resposta tem mais detalhes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta colocar `text-align:right` na `<ul>` e não `float` na `<li>`

Veja como fica:

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.menu ul {
  width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.menu ul li:first-child {
  margin: 0 11px 0 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 39px;
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: .9s;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fc2827;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.menu ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #000;
}

.menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}

.menu ul ul li a {
  text-align: left;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pesquisar</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="sub_menu">pesquisar</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Reportar erro</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gêneros</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="sub_menu">generos</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Outra forma para corrigir isso é não usar o `float`, mas usar `display:flex` e alinhar os itens no final com `justify-content:flex-end` (a direita) do elemento pai

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.menu ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.menu ul li:first-child {
  margin: 0 11px 0 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 39px;
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: .9s;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fc2827;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.menu ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #000;
}

.menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}

.menu ul ul li a {
  text-align: left;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pesquisar</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="sub_menu">pesquisar</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Reportar erro</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gêneros</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="sub_menu">generos</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: certinho, você é zka mano

Comment: @Bruno é nois que voa bruxão! Tmj []´s